# Ошибка при запросе к бд: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Tags: php, mysql, sql, warning

```
$db = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pswd) || die("Не могу соединиться с MySQL.");
mysql_select_db($database,$db) || die("Не могу подключиться к базе.");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT vk_id FROM history WHERE name='$sel'",$db) || die(mysql_error());
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in...

Знаю, что подобных тем много, перерыл их все, но решение своей проблемы не нашел.

Comment: В `$sel` что-то есть? `"SELECT vk_id FROM history WHERE name='".$sel."';"` пробовали? В `history` есть указанные колонки? `$sel` не содержит одинарные кавычки?

Comment: это, конечно, не дубликат, но учитывая тупость гугла, его все равно никто не найдет, так что вопрос можно смело выкидывать. А всем пытливым естествоиспытателям можно порекомендовать не стараться выглядеть умнее всех. Тебя кто-то силком заставлял менять or на две палки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте заменить строчку:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT vk_id FROM history WHERE name='$sel'",$db) || die(mysql_error());
```

На:

```
($result = mysql_query("SELECT vk_id FROM history WHERE name='$sel'",$db)) || die(mysql_error());
```

В Вашем варианте переменной `$result` присваивается булево выражение из:

```
mysql_query() || die()
```

Ошибки связанные с декорированием кавычек будут выдаваться в `die(mysql_error())`. Переменную `$sel` необходимо обязательно проверить на наличие кавычек.

Comment: Почему вы пишете комментарии, а просто не поправите ответ?